# Handwriting to LaTeX?

Tags: android, math, latex, writing, screenwriting

Usa there an Android app which will convert math handwriting to LaTeX? I have seen some apps like photomath on Android that take pictures of textbook math and solve the problem but I just want LaTeX from my handwriting.

Thanks.